# TSQL - Returning the result of a stored procedure from a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a function to return a list of files in a directory so that I can call the function in a `SELECT` statement. Yes I could use a stored procedure, but then I would need to use a cursor.

This is what I want to do, but this gives the error

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetFilesInDirectory] 
     (@Path VARCHAR(512), 
      @FileMask VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS @Files TABLE (
    FilePath VARCHAR(512)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Cmd VARCHAR(8000)  
    SET @cmd = 'dir ' + quotename(@Path + @FileMask, NCHAR(34)) + ' /B' 

    INSERT INTO @Files (FilePath)
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

    RETURN 
END
```

Funnily enough, this is valid:

```
INSERT INTO @Files (FilePath) SELECT 'test.txt'
```

and this is valid without the INSERT before it:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

But combining them is not.

Any suggestions on another approach to this.

Comment: I've certainly spammed `xp_cmdshell` to read the file system more than enough myself - but if you're doing this often enough and in the context that you're need it in a table-valued function, have you considered just reading the directory location as a part of procedural or SSIS job and querying your data from a user table location that this would write to?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) clearly specifies that this is not possible:

> **Calling Extended Stored Procedures from Functions**
>
> The extended stored procedure, when it is called from inside a
>   function, cannot return result sets to the client. Any ODS APIs that
>   return result sets to the client will return FAIL. The extended stored
>   procedure could connect back to an instance of SQL Server; however, it
>   should not try to join the same transaction as the function that
>   invoked the extended stored procedure.

I am not sure where this limitation comes from.  The suggested work-around is a hack, but it might work.  Call an extended stored procedure that executes a shell script that connects to the database that populates a table with the results of the shell command into another table.  The use the results from that table.  There might be some transactional issues.

I don't fully understand the advantage of putting this logic in a function.  I admit it might seem convenient.  But, if you are iterating through files -- say to load them -- then you need to execute stored procedures on each one.  If you are loading a table, you can do so through a stored procedure, using the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly that the `INSERT INTO table EXEC proc;` construct creates an internal Transaction, and you aren't allowed to use Transactions in T-SQL functions (Scalar UDF and Multi-statement TVF; Inline TVF isn't relevant here as it can only be a `SELECT` statement).

However, this is rather trivial to handle via a SQLCLR TVF. You can use classes like `FileSystemInfo` and `DirectoryInfo`, etc., to enumerate files in directories in several different ways (i.e. with or without passing in filters that can include the `*` and `?` wildcards, recursive through subdirectories or not). You just need to mark the Assembly as `WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. And you do *not* need (or want) to set the DB to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`, but instead sign the Assembly, create an Asymmetric Key in `[master]` from the signed Assembly, create a Login from that Asymmetric Key, and then grant that Login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission. For more information on working with SQLCLR, please see the series I am writing on that topic at SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (that site does require free registration, but it's definitely worth it). Level 7 in particular shows how to handle doing the security properly when using Visual Studio/SSDT.

For anyone who doesn't want to deal with doing any development, I wrote a library of SQLCLR functions and stored procedures called [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) that includes several file system functions, including **File_GetDirectoryListing** which does exactly this. It is a streaming TVF so it is very fast / efficient, and allows for RegEx filters on Filename and Path instead of the standard `*` and `?` wildcards. However, just FYI: it is only available in the Full version, not in the Free version.